# Create .exe with pyinstaller APP Tkinter Aspocells

Tags: python, tkinter, jvm, pyinstaller, jpype

I'm trying to package a Python app with Tkinter interface and asposecell but when I start the .exe it gives me this error;

```
 traceback(most recent call last):
 File"org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jPypeContext.callMethod
 Exception: Java Exception

 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 Traceback(most recent call last):
 File"jpype\imports.py" line 195, in find_spec
 java.lang.java.ClassNotFoundException:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aspose

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

traceback(most recent call last):
File "grafico.py", line 11, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
File "aposecells\api.py", line 10, in <module>
File "jpype\imports.py" line 203, in find_spec>
Error:Failed to import 'com.aspose'

In the project folder it works correctly, these are the imported modules;
os
jpype
asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
asposecells.api imp *
shutil
```

I have JPype1-1.4.1.dist-info in the python folder, \Lib\sites.packages and Jpype in the same location
since it asked me to install JPype1 when trying to install dry jpype.

I have tried to package in more than one file and with programs like py2exe without success, I hope to be able to finish the work to .exe

Comment: create a [mre].